# Openlayers : Layers not superposed properly

Tags: openlayers, markers, tms

I try to make a map using a TMS layer and a Boxes layer.

[My exemple](http://new.ledisun.com/test/)

My map is built like this :

```
`var get_my_url = function (bounds) {
    var res = this.map.getResolution();
    var x = Math.round ((bounds.left - this.maxExtent.left) / (res * this.tileSize.w));
    var y = Math.round ((this.maxExtent.top - bounds.top) / (res * this.tileSize.h));
    var zoom = this.map.getZoom();

    var path = '433-' + zoom + "-" + x + "-" + y + "." + this.type; 
    var url = this.url;
    if (url instanceof Array) {
        url = this.selectUrl(path, url);
    }
    return url + path;
}

var maxSize = 3872;
var mapHeight = 2592;
var tileSize = 256;

var options = {
    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(0,0,maxSize,maxSize),
    maxResolution: maxSize / tileSize,
    numZoomLevels: 5
};

var map = new OpenLayers.Map(
    'map',
    options
);`
```

My TMS layer is built like that :

```
`var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.TMS(
    'Aerial',
    '<?php print site_url(); ?>/wp-content/uploads/map-tiles/',
    {
        type: 'png',
        getURL: get_my_url,
        layername: "basic",
        isBaseLayer: true
    }
);`
```

And finally, my Boxes layer is built like that :

```
`var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(<?php print $box_x ?>, <?php print $box_y ?>, <?php print $box_x + $box_w ?>, <?php print $box_y + $box_h ?>);
box = new OpenLayers.Marker.Box(bounds);
box.events.register("click", box, function (e) {
    this.setBorder("yellow");
});

var boxes  = new OpenLayers.Layer.Boxes( 
    'Boxes',
    {
        layername: "juzbox",
        isBaseLayer: false
    }
);
boxes.addMarker(box);`
```

Now, I just add the layers to my map and setCenter on my map like :

```
`map.addLayers([layer, boxes]);

var lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(maxSize/2, maxSize-(mapHeight/2));
lonlat.transform(map.displayProjection, map.baseLayer.projection);
map.setCenter(lonlat, 2);`
```

My problem is that my layers are not superposed but the second is under the first...

Need some help !!

Comment: I forgot to give a link... http://new.ledisun.com/test/ The red box should appear over the girl's head. Instead, it's added under the baselayer...

Answer (score 1):

Wow !! One day and a half to solve this... I think I'm just stupid sometimes... :)

Note for later : 0,0 is the bottom-left of the map, not the top-left !!!

So the problem was just in the bounds of boxes layer.

```
var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(<?php print $box_x ?>, maxSize - <?php print $box_y + $box_h ?>, <?php print $box_x + $box_w ?>, maxSize - <?php print $box_y ?>);
```

And it works... take a look at [the exemple](http://new.ledisun.com/test/)